# How to stop the reuse of an Component in Angular 2 RC2 "2.0.0-rc.2 (2016-06-15)"

Tags: angularjs, angular

I was working with angular 2 RC1 version and had implemented navigation where I have nested structure where I can navigate from a Component (A) to the same Component (A) but do not want to angular to reuse the Component (achieving full navigation history). So what I used to do was implement the `CanReuse` in my Component and `return false`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { CanReuse } from "@angular/router-deprecated";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "myComponent",
    templateUrl: "myComponent.component.html"
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, CanReuse {
   private _sub: any;

   constructor(private _router: Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {

   }

   ngOnInit() {
       this._sub = this._router
        .routerState
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
            var parentTitle = params['id'];
            var tappedTitle = params['title'];
        });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
       this._sub.unsubscribe();
   }

   public onNavigationButtonTap(args) {
       this._router.navigate(['/myComponent'], { queryParams: { id: 1, title: "My title" } });
   }

   routerCanReuse(nextInstruction: any, prevInstruction: any): boolean {
        return false;
   }
}
```

The navigation is triggered by the `onNavigationButtonTap()` function.

And the routes used by the Bootstrap are:

```
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: "/", redirectTo: "/myComponent", terminal: true },
    { path: "/myComponent", component: MyComponent }
];
```

Since I updated to **RC2** it looks like this is not longer applicable and I have trouble finding out how to do the same in the new new angular router `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: How do you navigate with the new router so that it doesn't maintain full history?

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer I edited my post to include the full Component code.

Answer (score 1):

Until we get canReuse back, I'm using a dummy 'redirect' component that simply redirects to the desired component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'redirect',
  template: ``
})
export class RedirectComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let url = this.route.snapshot.url
    console.log('redirect', this.route.toString())
    this.router.navigate(url.map((seg) => seg.path))
  }
}
```

and the link is something like

```
 '/redirect/some/page/1/2'
```

RouterConfig like

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
{
  path: 'redirect',
  children: [
    {
      path: '**',
      component: RedirectComponent
    }
  ]
},
```